# Storing form variables through java script

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have made few textfields through javascript. But I have no clue how to store them into database while submitting the form. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
      if(name=='Other') {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
      }
      else if(name=="School") {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Name of the School : <input type="text" name="school" />'; 
        document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='Contact Number : <input type="text" name="contact" />'; 
      }
      else {
       document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
       document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
     }
   }
 </script>

<html>
<select name="how" class="subtitle" id="select" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">>
                          <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Please select</option>
                          <option>School</option>
                          <option>Consultant</option>
                          <option>WhatApp</option>
                          <option>Brochure / Poster</option>
                          <option>Internet</option>
                          <option>Other</option>
                        </select></td>
</html>
```

In the above html, when 'School' or 'Other' option is selected, it will show more text fields from javascript. But I could not store the value of that text fields. But all the other options are getting inserted into the database. Please help to fix this.

Comment: You first need a form, server, server-sided language, and a database. I'm only seeing the client-sided code you provided, I can't say anything about the back-end with the information provided.

Comment: you are missing the part where you write to the database, which like you said "But all the other options are getting inserted into the database." where is this part?

Comment: First, this is invalid html code (e.g </td>)
Second, there is no form element and submit button at all

Comment: Is this your entire code? Where is the form tag? Where does the submitting occur?

Comment: Yeah I have everything, I use php mysql, I want to know only how to get the value from the javascript generated textfield. This is not the entire code

Answer (score 1):

Getting values from html fields can be done on multiple ways, this is just one of them:

```
<form onsubmit='onSubmit();'>
<input type="text" id="variableName" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function onSubmit(){
var val = document.getElementById('variableName').value;
console.log(val);
}
</script>
```

This way gets what user typed into input field.

Is this what you wanted to achieve? Hope that helps...